# Rename and replace an image in my images folder php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a newbie working on an app in which i allow users to upload their pics and when they need to change the pic I can't delete the old pic and hence cant rename too. Here's my code to upload an img as per tutorial in codeigniter.

```
        $config['upload_path'] = './img/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';
        $config['file_name'] = $id.'_img';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( $this->upload->do_upload())
        {

                $this->view_data['message'] = "File Uploaded";
        }
```

Here I pass the user id and hence need to rename and replace the old image with the name like 44_img..... Any help would be appreciated , Thanks in advance....

Comment: You want to rename but you can't rename? Is that because you don't know how are are you not allowed by the server?

Comment: an existing pic is 44_img.jpg and if i add the new pic then it is named as 44_img1.jpg

Comment: Renaming, deleting and uploading an image are different actions and should be treated this way. Where do you try to rename the file?

Comment: actually i need help in deleting the file only if file exists before i upload the pic

Comment: would it not just get overridden if the file already exist?

Comment: I didnt expect this... b'coz of so many responses for my question I've solved the issue.. Thnaks to y'all guys..... I'm happy and satisfied...

Answer (score 3):

Try this for deletion of the old file:

```
$oldfile   = $config['upload_path'].$config['file_name'];
if( file_exists( $oldfile ) ){
    unlink( $oldfile );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$this->upload->data()` to retrieve data related to upload, and inside do something like that:

```
  if ( $this->upload->do_upload())
  {

     $this->view_data['message'] = "File Uploaded";
     $data = $this->upload->data();
     $path = $data['full_path'];
     $dir  = dirname($path);
     $ext  = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

     if(rename($path, $dir.'/'.$your_file_new_name.'.'.$ext)) {
        $this->view_data['message'] .= '<br/> And renamed';
     }
  }
```

Note that you must have enough rights to upload your files, especially write righths on a directory you want to upload to. Also, good practice is to give files unique names and separate them into user related directories. For example, you can combine mysql users id with image id.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to over write the existing one, i.e., delete the older one and save new one with same name then

```
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE; 
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

if you want to keep both, better save the new one with old one, the code will automatically rename the new one and you can save the name of new uploaded image to access it

```
$config['overwrite'] = FALSE; 
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
if ($this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $uploaded_filename = $this->CI->upload->file_name; //name of the save image
    $this->view_data['message'] = "File Uploaded";
}
```

Comment: Hey Deepanshu, It will delete other image with same name. If I want to delete the specific image corresponding to that row, it will not work.. :)